# Configuring Activemq web console to use LDAP for authorization and authentication

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, jetty, activemq-classic

I'm getting the following error when configuring activemq web console to use ldap for authentication and authorization. I'm using a free online test ldap for this http://www.forumsys.com/en/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/ and get the following error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService.login(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/UserIdentity; 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.login(LoginAuthenticator.java:61)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator.validateRequest(BasicAuthenticator.java:92)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:512)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730] 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_101]
```

Please see my jetty.xml and login.conf configuration sections and advise.

login conf

```
LDAPLogin { 
  org.apache.activemq.jaas.LDAPLoginModule required 
    debug=true 
    initialContextFactory=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory 
    connectionURL="ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389" 
    connectionUsername="cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com" 
    connectionPassword=password 
    connectionProtocol="" 
    authentication=simple 
    userBase="dc=example,dc=com" 
    userSearchMatching="(uid={0})" 
    userSearchSubtree=false 
    roleBase="dc=example,dc=com" 
    roleName=ou 
    roleSearchMatching="(ou=scientists)" 
    roleSearchSubtree=false 
    ; 
};
```

jetty.xml

```
<bean id="ldapLoginService" class="org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService">
        <property name="name" value="LdapRealm" />
        <property name="loginModuleName" value="LDAPLogin" />
        <property name="roleClassNames" value="org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASRole" />
        <property name="identityService" ref="identityService" />
    </bean>

<bean id="securityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
        <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
        <property name="roles" value="scientists" />

        <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
    </bean>

<bean id="securityHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
        <property name="loginService" ref="ldapLoginService" />
        <property name="identityService" ref="identityService" />
        <property name="realmName" value="LdapRealm" />
        <property name="authenticator">
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator" />
        </property>
        <property name="constraintMappings">
            <list>
                <ref bean="adminSecurityConstraintMapping" />
                <ref bean="securityConstraintMapping" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="handler" ref="secHandlerCollection" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.lang.AbstractMethodError means an abstract method is being invoked. It is possible that the JAAS modules of Jetty are not enabled ; meaning JAAS related jars are not available in the classpath. Take look at step 3 in the below link on enabling JAAS modules.

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/jaas-support.html#jaas-configuration